Eclipse 2024-09 Is there a way to get the old Find/Replace window back?
In Eclipse 2024-09, The find/replace window has been changed to this:

Is there a setting to get the old find/replace window back? This search bar is useless compared to the old one. You can't select wrap options, text selection, or many other things.
Here is a screenshot of the older find/replace:


What do you mean by "text selection"? The Select All button of the old Find/replace dialog is in the new find/replace overlay the text selection icon with the two magnifying glasses. There is also an icon to set the scope to the selected lines.

In the preferences, General > Editors > Text Editors untick the checkbox Use find/replace overlay to get the old Find/Replace dialog back:

See also:

Eclipse 4.33 - New and Noteworthy - Platform and Equinox - Overlay for Performing Find/Replace Operations
My "Eclipse 2024-09 Java IDE Improvements" video demonstrating the new find/replace overlay and how to deactivate it


To be precise, the complete path is actually Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors - but yess, worked for me yeuyyy I have my own-controlled-replace back !

On Windows and Linux the preferences are in Window > Preferences, on macOS in the application menu.

I incorporated the information in this answer into the accepted answer.
